# Creating custom path for physics body in SpriteKit

Tags: swift, skspritenode, skphysicsbody

Trying to create custom path for bucket's physicsbody, but had a problem

The main idea is put ball in bucket. Ball spawn in touch location on screen and fall to ground. But it never flies to bucket. As I understood physics body bigger than texture, but I don't know why.

code:

```
func spawnBucket() -> SKSpriteNode {
        let bucketTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "bucket_1")
        let bucket = SKSpriteNode(texture: bucketTexture)
        bucket.position = CGPoint(x: self.screenSize.width / 2 , y: 200)
        bucket.zPosition = 3

        let offsetX = bucket.frame.size.width * bucket.anchorPoint.x
        let offsetY = bucket.frame.size.height * bucket.anchorPoint.y

        let path = CGMutablePath()

        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 74 - offsetX, y: 72 - offsetY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 58 - offsetX, y: 225 - offsetY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 53 - offsetX, y: 233 - offsetY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 66 - offsetX, y: 241 - offsetY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 80 - offsetX, y: 218 - offsetY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 147 - offsetX, y: 202 - offsetY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 199 - offsetX, y: 213 - offsetY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 227 - offsetX, y: 224 - offsetY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 227 - offsetX, y: 238 - offsetY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 234 - offsetX, y: 229 - offsetY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 226 - offsetX, y: 204 - offsetY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 223 - offsetX, y: 172 - offsetY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 211 - offsetX, y: 74 - offsetY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 178 - offsetX, y: 57 - offsetY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 139 - offsetX, y: 54 - offsetY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 107 - offsetX, y: 56 - offsetY))

        path.closeSubpath()
        bucket.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(polygonFrom: path)
//        bucket.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: bucketTexture, size: bucket.size)
        return bucket
    }
```

[picture1,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/el0BN.jpg) 
[picture2(trying to create physics body like that)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwR8J.png)
How can I realise that idea? Or I am wrong at all?

[UPD: physics body creating in different place](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pi22e.jpg)

after I wrote code: `bucket.setscale(1.5)`
[got that result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEcze.jpg)

Comment: When trying to debug physics issues, first turn on the view's `showsPhysics`property. That will often help you figure out what's going on. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skview/1520389-showsphysics

Comment: thank you for your reply, I tried and i see that physics body creating in different place, don't know why. when I creating physics body only with texture I don't have any problems but I want to put ball in bucket, so I decided to make custom path and got that:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pi22e.jpg

Comment: If you produced the path from pixel coordinates in the bucket texture, then you might have a factor of 2 off if the texture is a 2x asset. I.e., an @2x texture of say 100x100 pixels is 50x50 points in terms of rendering, and the points in the path should correspond to 50x50.

Comment: I  wrote code: bucket.setscale(1.5) and got that result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEcze.jpg , Now I understand approximately in what way i should think, thank you for your help :)